# Html classes aren't being recognized in razor?

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

So I'm designing a webpage that takes user input, converts it into the body of an email, then sends said email to my email account. I'm following this guide from microsoft: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Send-an-email-using-aspnet-80195a1f

It uses `@using (Html.BeginForm("email", "Home", FormMethod.Post))` to call the ActionResult method and has the html form itself within the brackets of the Html.BeginForm. This makes enough sense to me - until i launched my page only to see that each class in my form has been completely ignored by the css page for some reason. I copy/pasted the form outside of the Html.BeginForm brackets and ta da! My css is there again. I've read a couple different tutorials/posts regarding what I'm trying to do here and it doesn't sound like anyone else has really had this problem...Any ideas?

For reference my html page is:

```
    @model CuttingEdgeWebsite2._0.Models.ServiceRequest

@using (Html.BeginForm("Email", "ServiceRequestsController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="servicesReq">
        <form class="serviceReqForm" action="mailto:carl@cuttingedgelighting.com?Subject=Service%20Request" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="col-left">
                <label>
                    <span class="required">* </span><span>Name:</span><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestName" required />
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span class="required">* </span><span>Email:</span><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestEmail" required />
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span>Company:</span><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestCompany" />
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span>Address:</span><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestAddress" />
                </label><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="serviceTypeGrid">
                <span class="required">* </span><span>Please choose what type of servicing you require:</span><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-left2">
                <label class="serviceType">
                    <input type="radio" name="serviceType" value="Electrical" /> Electrical<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="serviceType" value="Lighting" /> Lighting<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="serviceType" value="Energy" /> Energy<br />
                    <input type="radio" name="serviceType" value="Multiple" /> Multiple<br />
                </label><br /><br />
            </div>
            <div class="col-right">
                <label>
                    <span>City:</span><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestCity" />
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span>State:</span><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestState" />
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span>Zip Code:</span><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestZip" />
                </label><br />
                <label>
                    <span class="required">* </span><span>Phone Number:</span><br />
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestNumber" />
                </label><br />
            </div>
            <label class="commentText">
                <span>Comments:</span><br />
                <textarea name="comments"></textarea><br />
            </label>
            <div class="formSubmitButton">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
                <br />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Can you share some of the CSS that isn't being applied correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not be sure now, but I believe that the error and that you are creating one  within another, the Html.BeginForm command creates a form.

```
<div class="servicesReq">
@using (Html.BeginForm("Email", "ServiceRequestsController", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "serviceReqForm" }))
{   <div class="col-left">
    <label>
        <span class="required">* </span><span>Name:</span><br />
        <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestName" required />
    </label><br />
    <label>
        <span class="required">* </span><span>Email:</span><br />
        <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestEmail" required />
    </label><br />
    <label>
        <span>Company:</span><br />
        <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestCompany" />
    </label><br />
    <label>
        <span>Address:</span><br />
        <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestAddress" />
    </label><br /><br />
</div>
    <div class="serviceTypeGrid">
        <span class="required">* </span><span>Please choose what type of servicing you require:</span><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-left2">
        <label class="serviceType">
            <input type="radio" name="serviceType" value="Electrical" /> Electrical<br />
            <input type="radio" name="serviceType" value="Lighting" /> Lighting<br />
            <input type="radio" name="serviceType" value="Energy" /> Energy<br />
            <input type="radio" name="serviceType" value="Multiple" /> Multiple<br />
        </label><br /><br />
    </div>
    <div class="col-right">
        <label>
            <span>City:</span><br />
            <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestCity" />
        </label><br />
        <label>
            <span>State:</span><br />
            <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestState" />
        </label><br />
        <label>
            <span>Zip Code:</span><br />
            <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestZip" />
        </label><br />
        <label>
            <span class="required">* </span><span>Phone Number:</span><br />
            <input class="input" type="text" name="ServiceRequestNumber" />
        </label><br />
    </div>
    <label class="commentText">
        <span>Comments:</span><br />
        <textarea name="comments"></textarea><br />
    </label>
    <div class="formSubmitButton">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" /><br />
        <br />
    </div>
}
```

Comment: of course, I knew it had to be something stupidly simple. I actually made the form first for a different purpose, and then copy/pasted into the razor brackets so I'm not surprised I missed that. Solution works and everything checks out!